# Webpack 5 - develop package mounted in node_module

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

the question is quite simple. I have a project where I'm using developed npm package.
I want to configure dev environment that I could edit both: source code of my application and  one package from node_module folder.
so the structure is something like

```
- frontend <- want to edit this files
  - node modules
    ...
    -my-own-package
```

the issue is that I can see that web server is reacting to "my-own-package" changes , but the result is kind of cached or something.
I can't see changes in my code.
I was trying to disable cache, but webpack-dev server goes in to inifinite recomile loop.
How can I do it properly?

mydev webpack config lloks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const common = require('./webpack.common.config')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",


  entry: ["./index.js",path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/my-own-package")],
  devServer: {
      port: 80,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      historyApiFallback: true,
      disableHostCheck: true,
      watchOptions: {
          aggregateTimeout: 500,
          poll: 1000,
            
      }
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", //2. Inject styles into DOM
          "css-loader" //1. Turns css into commonjs
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

As I learned there is no such an option at the moment.
the workaround is to play around with resole
just put your library in a folder next to the frontend ( in my case "dependencies")

```
module.exports = merge(common,
   {​​​​​  mode: "development",  
   resolve: {
​​​​​         modules: ['dependencies' , 'node_modules' ], 
   }​​​​​,
```

then it's fine.